# Dropdownbutton Statemanagement - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, web-applications, state-management

I want to create an evaluation app in flutter with multiple dropdownbuttons. The dropdownbuttons should contain a text with a value, for example: dropdownbutton1: "Text"; Value(2), dropdownbutton2: "Text"; Value2(4) and there is also an another button "evaluate", if i click on the "evaluate" button it should go to the next screen and the next screen displays the total of the value (it should be 6= value(2) + value2(4).

My next thought would be statemanagement, but i dont know how to do it right now.
I searched everywhere in the internet but couldnt find anything.

I am new to flutter. Is there a way to do it with statemanagement and how it could be look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you should implement a flavor of state management, both for the communication between the pages as well as to feed data to the dropdown menus, and holding on to the selected values from the dropdowns.

My suggestion would be to go with something as simple as the **Provider** state management strategy, and leverage the widgets that facilitate listening to changes occurring on the application. This strategy makes your app more decouples, maintains a clean separation of concerns and allows for good maintenance.

You can create a **Provided** service (i.e. DropdownService) that holds to the values of the dropdown menus as a list of dropdown options, as well as two properties that hold on to the selected values from the dropdowns (i.e. selectedFirstOption, selectedSecondOption). Upon triggering changes on both **DropDownButton** widgets, you can trigger a notification for the widget to rebuild itself, updating its selections, and holding on to the selected value.

A button will trigger the evaluation and navigation to the next page, only if both **selectedFirstOption** and **selectedSecondOption** are not null, then the next page also consumes the provided DropdownService, pulls the data persisted for both selections, add the values and displays it to the user.

I threw something together as an example to illustrate my point below:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => DropdownService()
        )
      ],
      child: MyApp()
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Consumer<DropdownService>(
      builder: (context, dropdownService, child) {
        return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text('First dropdown:'),
                DropdownButton<DropdownOption>(
                  value: dropdownService.selectedFirstOption,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  elevation: 16,
                  onChanged: (DropdownOption? newValue) {
                      dropdownService.selectedFirstOption = newValue!;
                  },
                  items: dropdownService.firstDropdown.map((DropdownOption option) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<DropdownOption>(
                      value: option,
                      child: Text(option.text!),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                const Text('Second dropdown:'),
                DropdownButton<DropdownOption>(
                  value: dropdownService.selectedSecondOption,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  elevation: 16,
                  onChanged: (DropdownOption? newValue) {
                      dropdownService.selectedSecondOption = newValue!;
                  },
                  items: dropdownService.secondDropdown.map((DropdownOption option) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<DropdownOption>(
                      value: option,
                      child: Text(option.text!),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Material(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: dropdownService.selectedFirstOption != null 
                      && dropdownService.selectedSecondOption != null ? () {
                      
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage())
                      );
                    } : null,
                    child: const Text('Evaluate', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
                    )
                  )
                )
              ]
            )
          );
      }
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DropdownService dropdownService = Provider.of<DropdownService>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('The result of ${dropdownService.selectedFirstOption!.text!} and ${dropdownService.selectedSecondOption!.text!}:'),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('${dropdownService.selectedFirstOption!.value! + dropdownService.selectedSecondOption!.value!}',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 50)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownService extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  List<DropdownOption> firstDropdown = [
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (5)', value: 5),
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (6)', value: 6),
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (7)', value: 7),
  ];
  
  DropdownOption? _selectedFirstOption; // = DropdownOption(text: 'Select Value', value: -1);
  DropdownOption? _selectedSecondOption; // = DropdownOption(text: 'Select Value', value: -1);

  DropdownOption? get selectedFirstOption => _selectedFirstOption;
  DropdownOption? get selectedSecondOption => _selectedSecondOption;

  set selectedFirstOption(DropdownOption? value) {
    _selectedFirstOption = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set selectedSecondOption(DropdownOption? value) {
    _selectedSecondOption = value;
    notifyListeners();
  } 
  
  List<DropdownOption> secondDropdown = [
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (1)', value: 1),
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (2)', value: 2),
    DropdownOption(text: 'Value (3)', value: 3),
  ];
}


class DropdownOption {
  String? text;
  double? value;
  
  DropdownOption({ this.text, this.value });
}
```

If you run this code (also provided as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/814c9539dd4cd25c49e978d419640459)) through **DartPad.dev**, you should see the following output:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if the answer was useful to you and it worked out for your purposes, that way we can mark this answer as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: My problem right now is that i want to use the dropdownbuttons in several screens. And the screens do have like 3-4 dropdown buttons. Would it be a problem for onpressed function? It should look like this: https://gyazo.com/f00af1273a67b5619789adcf476b8706, https://gyazo.com/9608986907db2eb5db0e9168eb67402d

Comment: Not a problem whatsoever. Make sure to create a DropdownOption list for each of those dropdowns and a property to hold their selections. You can create custom widgets that consume the service that feeds them their data and capture their selections. There won't be a problem with the onPressed function because you will create a function that sets each individual dropdown. Now what you want should be addressed as a separate question to avoid polluting this one, so let's close this one (mark as correct if it helped you) and open up another one addressing your new issue. Thanks!